# Sending a HashMap object to Java Servlet using C#

Tags: c#, servlets

I have a Java Servlet application and I have a Java client that works. It simply creates a URLConnection object and an ObjectOutputStream and then just writes the Hashmap object.

How do i do the same in C# since it has no "Hashmap" class. If I use something like a "Dictionary" class, how's the Java servlet side gonna handle it? will it get parsed into a Hashmap object properly? Is C# and Servlet interoperable?

Thanks

Comment: what is underlying type of the ObjectOutputStream ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it would not be converted automatically. You've to use some standard format like [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)/[XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)/[CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and serialize/parse it yourself or use Serialziation Frameworks like [Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), [ZeroC Ice](http://www.zeroc.com/) which supports both Java and .NET but again you have to provide you own conversion from Hashmap to Framework's data structures since built in structures are primitives and arrays.